# How to add 'this' to a object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

So I created the greeting method, but I am having trouble trying to return the string with the this method. All help would be greatly appreciated please.

```
function exerciseTwo(userObj){
    // Exercise Two: You will be given an object called 'userObj'

    // userObject will already have a key on it called 'name'

    // Add a method to userObj, called 'greeting'.

    // Using the keyword 'this', the greeting method should return the following string:

    // 'Hi, my name is ' and the users name.

    // eg: If userObj has a name: 'Dan', greeting should return: Hi, my name is Dan'

    // NOTE: DO NOT create a new object.

    // NOTE: DO NOT create a key called name the key is already on the object.

    userObj.greeting = 'Hi, my name is ' + this.name;

    return userObj;
}
```

Comment: Clue: `userObj.greeting = 'Hi, my name is ' + this.name;` isn't a method.

Comment: Step 1: Create a function

Comment: Are you trying to get us to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the function without creating any new objects and call the function, this will have the scope of where you call the function from, which will be window, so you can either create a var name with the value 'users name' or set a property on window directly with window.name = 'users name';

this in JavaScript is a bit loopy.

```js
var name = 'Dan';

console.log(window.name);

function exerciseTwo(userObj){
    userObj.greeting = 'Hi, my name is ' + this.name;

    return userObj;
}

console.log(exerciseTwo({}));
```

In the browser DOM you have a window object that is the namespace for everything the page does, so calling exerciseTwo when you are not in an object, this will resolve to window. All variables you create without a namespace will be attached to the window object.

```js
var userObj = { // An object with the name property as Dan
  name: 'Dan'
}

userObj.greeting = function () { // Adding a function to the object called greeting
  return 'Hi, my name is ' + this.name;
}

console.log(userObj.greeting());
```

In this instance, when the function is called this has the scope of the object userObj.